# Darlington Triplet

Tags: darlington

I was playing around in Falstad Circuit Simulator with powering a 2.5V incandescent lamp with a Darlington Triplet.  I tried it two different ways and got slightly different results.
I'm not sure if either is technically correct, and I also don't understand what is causing the results to be different.  This is just theoretical and I don't have a practical application for this, but I'd like to understand what is happening in each of the circuits.
I've tried to figure it out myself but it's beyond my beginner level.  I'd really appreciate any and all beginner-level explanations.  Thanks!

[Circuit 1:](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcsDMYBM6EA4GTClgOwBsJIZISeVApgLRhgBQA7letiOgCyQdd0RdFDbgS-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-OxlwoHTHlFHJWL+JgZ2I6yNs3P7cK1Es+UA)
[image]

[Circuit 2:](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAWIosgoFMBaMMAKADcRC88QUUAWTt3AZCUcf1rZxtGAhYB3ITzCjl4FDxSL1YTesKDIOlAjGHwhWheMAXENgQpe+B3kFoetCAxhhIYASE2HgYKNjEJPxIMIQoxJR4xPxkGJAJFv60ACZ0AGYAhgCuADa2Oinmgk48Njohghb8YFVQOgj8jdVqdUo1vGHqmM7GSi3exM7jlrIs9vx4tHzV+sviPjA4YPym2Nhp-oQI6VDQGAuRxJDNyWSEWMg5+cVl7foWHV1tSs2t-BZ1AAe4EmIB2IDCgmiYN4ggAIgUAE4lACWADsAOa2AD2aIAOgBnAAqiJRAAcSnRbIScYSAArYhR0RGEgr4gkASTRAGM2bkCdy6GjqQSADIFAC2ZJYgQgCDUkQoam2RnACDACGglGwAkieD0pnA0HCvGg-1OcAgMEtLERM04gmm0288Hgc1hE2cwxBI3Ap0kSUgJAIAiD+3Icn8OD2UUWez4jxAuUKpXKSgaDoc2Fao14ZkzMczue9ngcThcPGw9XcPrcjqs3wGUzU3udOidoNDtarfVWkgoq0Gua4WkGI94AkbCyWk4zax7YMVTQBRjeWlc-Tb6Zr01bDdzm4bGa3A5UDbM3n37Qb03lYhPd-tj5VDnaPUawl6SrEisfdSAA)
[image]

Comment: You can get much closer [choosing a PNP for Q2, Q1 collector connected to base of Q2, Q1 emitter to Q3 emitter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sziklai_pair).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference in the two is related to where the first and second transistors in the triplet get their collector current. Your first circuit matches the description of what they call a "Darlington triplet", while your second circuit (with multiple emitters) would be better characterized as a cascade of two common-collector buffers (with the base as the only load) followed by a common-emitter amplifier/low-side switch

The important structural difference of the darlington pair/triplet is that all of the collectors are connected together. This allows you to consider the triplet as its own three-terminal device:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6I2om.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your observation of "slightly different results" is a bit ambiguous, but I'm assuming that you're talking about the different voltage across the load. Each BJT has a base-to-emitter drop of about 0.7 V (because of the forward-biased base-emitter PN junction), and a saturation voltage of around 0.03-0.3 (depending on collector current) V from collector to emitter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCoQTl.png)</sup>

As a result, the minimum voltage drop across this whole structure is around 1.5 V: two times a 0.7 V diode drop<sup>1</sup>, plus a saturation voltage for Q3. Thus, the darlington triplet looks like a BJT with a much higher current gain, and a saturation voltage of around 1.5 V (a downside).

You can look at this as a sort of feedback structure: If Q1 draws more current, it causes the voltage drop across the load to increase, which drops the voltage at Q3's collector, causing the voltage to drop at Q3's emitter, Q2's base, Q2's emitter, and Q1's base. As the voltage at Q1's base decreases, Q1 would draw less current. Note that in the triplet, Q1 and Q2 are in "forward active" mode, while Q3 is in saturation.

On the other hand, your other structure receives collector current directly from the positive rail for the first two stages:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkkbq8.png)</sup>

Since Q3's emitter is now tied to the positive rail rather than the low side of the load, the load can now be driven with more current, until the voltage across Q1 reaches the saturation voltage. All three transistors can be driven fully on into saturation. This also means that the base currents are higher: Q2's collector current is 15 mA in this design (based on the simulation of the shown schematic) while the true darlington triplet only has 1 mA of Q2 collector current.

Note that in practice, this large saturation voltage for the triplet makes it annoying to use. Especially with low-power systems, excess voltage drops mean less headroom for useful signal swings. Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Darlington_transistor&oldid=1064223316#Darlington_triplet) on the darlington pair reads:

> A third transistor can be added to a Darlington pair to give even higher current gain, making a Darlington triplet. The emitter of the second transistor in the pair is connected to the base of the third, as the emitter of first transistor is connected to the base of the second, and the collectors of all three transistors are connected together. This gives current gain approximately equal to the product of the gains of the three transistors. However the increased current gain often does not justify the sensitivity and saturation current problems, so this circuit is seldom used.

<sup>1</sup> This will vary based on temperature and the actual current. Q3 carries the least current while Q1 carries the most; if they were identical transistors then Q3 would have a modestly smaller Vbe drop.

Comment: The second circuit could benefit from some series resistors, because otherwise it can have very large base current flowing through Q1.

Answer (score 1):

A *Darlington triplet* can figuratively be considered as three "nested" transistors (similar to Russian Matryoshka dolls). The idea of this connection can best be shown by building the circuit from right to left or from left to right.

## Building a Darlington triplet

In the schematics below, I have connected an imperfect ammeter Rc-100 with internal resistance of 100 Ω as a load to visualize the output current and a voltmeter Vout in parallel to the transistor to show the voltage drop across it.

I suppose that we control the base current through a resistor Rb connected between the base and Vcc.

### ... from right to left...

**1-transistor amplifier:** To apply all the supply voltage across the load, the transistor Q3 has to be saturated (on). If it has β = 100, then Rb = β.Rc = 10 kΩ, and only 220 mV are across Q3; the rest 9.8 V are across Rc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faTuZ3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**2-transistor amplifier:** Since we want to increase Rb = 100 kΩ, we decide to add another transistor Q2 before Q3 that is connected as a *common-collector*  stage. But a problem appears - since its collector is connected to Vcc, the Q2 collector current and accordingly, the Q3 base current is not limited.

We can solve this problem by inserting a resistor Rc2 between the Q2 collector and Vcc to limit the current. But here we (once Darlington) get a more clever idea: *Instead of increasing the resistance, can not we limit the current by decreasing the Q2 collector voltage*? We look around to see where there is such a decreasing voltage. Ah, there it is - that is the Q3 collector voltage. So just  we disconnect the Q2 collector from Vcc and connect it to the Q3 collector. Thus Q3 begins to decrease its collector voltage until it reaches the equilibrium point of 812 mV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftDUGh.png)</sup>

The name of this trick is *negative feedback*, and becauese the output voltage is applied in parallel to the Q3 input, it is a "parallel voltage-type negative feedback". Thus we reinvented the *Darlington pair*.

**3-transistor amplifier:** If we want to increase Rb even more (1 MΩ), we can add another transistor Q1 (CC stage) before the Darlington pair. We can limit the Q1 collector current by inserting a resistor Rc1 between its collector and Vcc but why not use the clever trick above? So we connect its collector to others. Thus the third transistor adds more gain to the total but also forces the collector voltage to rise another 0.7 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPSs0f.png)</sup>

### ... from left to right

In the same way we can build the  circuit but from left to right.

**1-transistor amplifier:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fab4BR.png)</sup>

**2-transistor amplifier:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXe1gr.png)</sup>

**3-transistor amplifier:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm0QXo.png)</sup>